# Make Table Names and Column Names Case Insensitive in MySQL

Tags: mysql, case-insensitive

I would like to be able to query the table Users and its columns UserName and Email case insensitively:

```
select username, email from users;
```

I know MySQL is case-insensitive for strings by default--that is not my question. I would like to query case-insensitive table and column names.

The SQL Server environment I work allows me to do so but don't know how to do so in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lower_case_table_names` system variable as described [in Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html). You can set this variable to the allowed value on start of `mysqld` or even in `my.cnf` config file